# Image upload dialog is not responsive, rendering it unusable on mobile

Tags: bug, uploader, responsive-design

The image upload dialog looks like this on mobile:

[image: screenshot]

Adding the image works, but it's not possible to click the *add picture* button.

Comment: I read about a responsive tool called [Filepond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/). Maybe they could use this...

Comment: I use the SE app to upload images to SE Imgur, then copy and paste the Markdown from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a little while now, there's been a [new image uploader](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links) that is entirely within the bounds of the post editor itself, and is responsive.

Thus, this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Not for profile pictures, tag wikis, and the profile’s “About me” section, though. See [Editor improvements for images and links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317622/289905).