# can't upload images to the new imgur upload thingie

Tags: bug

I would put an image here of the problem but I can't do that rn.

When will it be fixed.

Comment: The uploader was also failing for me earlier on mobile (Chrome Android). No error, just no upload happened after I picked my file. Was that what's happening for you?

Comment: @doppelgreener exactly. The visible state after choosing a file is identical to before. Also drag and drop doesn't work.

Comment: Browser and operating system, please?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog macOS Mojave 10.14, Safari 12.0

Comment: In that case, your issue is already reported here: [Stackoverflow's new image upload does not work on Mac Safari](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317596/stackoverflows-new-image-upload-does-not-work-on-mac-safari)