# Switch to the old image uploader if "Disable Responsiveness" button is enabled

Tags: feature-request, uploader

As of yesterday, a new image uploader has been introduced. This new uploader, while fitting in with the principles of responsive design, is causing quite a few glitches in a lot of different platforms. In the hours since it was rolled out, there have been two [documented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317611/cant-upload-images-to-the-new-imgur-upload-thingie) [cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317596/stackoverflows-new-image-upload-does-not-work-on-mac-safari) of it not working at all in certain platforms. (Both those links refer to the same platform, but the presence of a duplicate indicates how widespread it is.) Additionally, the "link from web" option is non-intuitive, [doesn't work at all on Internet Explorer 11](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317615/cannot-upload-images-from-web-links-in-internet-explorer-11-buttons-cut-off), and currently suffers from a focus bug in Chrome and Edge.

While these bugs are being sorted out, I think there should be a way to temporarily revert to the old upload UI. Since it's intended for responsive design, I suggest that if the user chooses to disable responsiveness, the old upload UI be shown instead (since responsiveness isn't important if it's disabled).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Focus bug should be fixed; just needs a bit of copy to make it more obvious.

Bugs with Safari should also be fixable, though I have no access to Safari so can only guess at what's happening there.

In general, the ideal outcome here is to *fix* bugs, not sweep them under the rug. The exception is probably IE11 - that works to a degree, but not sure how much time it's worth spending on improving that. Probably not much.

If something crops up that's absolutely *catastrophic* and can't be fixed in a reasonable amount of time... Then it's still possible to disable the new UI and roll back to the old one. Per-site, or everywhere. But that's not a great solution to... anything, really: the best outcome will always be to fix problems. So, let's do that.

Comment: Some people are forced to use IE11 in their workplace. Windows 10 LTSB has Edge disabled intentionally, and I occasionally use a Windows RT tablet. So I believe IE11 support is important.

Comment: And I guess some others may file bugs saying that "it no longer works in [obscure browser]". They should have the option of switching back to it.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Unless [obscure browser] is [officially supported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/258777), SE does not promise a seamlessly-working image uploader.

Comment: So is the bug report I filed for IE11, a *supported* browser, declined? Is fixing the image uploader there not something that's going to be done?

Comment: IE11 shouldn't be supported. The last two versions of Microsoft's browser are Edge and Edge (which was preceded by Edge). IE11 is at least four versions ago.

Comment: Well, fixing that "focus bug" will hopefully take less than the usual 6-8 months. (Sorry for weird edit, started by saying something else, edited only part)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog IE11 is still supported, but I can’t speak for the team regarding when (if ever) they’ll get around to fixing the bug.