# How to insert image by link using touch devices?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, touch-screen

In [new image insertion dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576) there is no explicit “insert image by link” action. As far as I know it’s possible by using keyboard insert hot keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> on Windows.

Is there a way to insert image by link on the web using touch screen devices like iPad without using external keyboard and manual Markdown edit?

Comment: There is no such way. I'm afraid Stack Exchange simply pays zero attention to mobile devices when developing new features, which is really sad. It cause such obvious overlooks of simple things, that are hard to fix after already done.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This wasn't overlooked, this was a known issue with the design. Not sure if that's better or worse than your assumption though :)

Comment: @balpha first, thanks for the reply, this alone is a good surprise. :) Second, well, I think it's a mistake to publish a new feature with such severe downsides. Better fix it internally, and roll it out when it's fully baked. And to be honest, being more responsive to such bugs would also be better (not you! I mean comments on bug reports in the announcement) but that's already overflowing to ranting, better suited in chat, not here. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

<s>There's currently no way to do that directly, which is the biggest problem with the "invisible" paste target.</s>

Right now your best workaround is to download the image with a browser and then upload it via the file picker.

Fortunately we have a design tweak in the works that will make this possible again.

This change was deployed yesterday.

Answer (score -2):

Copy the image link by long pressing/ touching and copying and paste by long pressing and selecting paste.

Comment: It seems that your answer is about editing markdown manually. This isn’t suitable for my question.

Comment: This answer is wrong, since the question is about touch devices. Long press on the image upload box does nothing, and does not let us paste.

Comment: @ShadowWizard long pressing is useful to open copy/paste menu for text edit boxes, but not for image upload editor.

Comment: @älёxölüt true, the image upload box is not a text box.