# Having suggestions when an image is too large to reduce size

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, images, uploader

Imagine this. You're uploading an image and then you get this error:

[image: Error]

Your image is too large and you don't know what to do.

How about below adding some suggestions on what to do? I personally use [tinypng.com](http://tinypng.com) to compress images and they are always under 2 MB. It's free as well.

If they don't want to do that they can crop their image or choose a different one.

The error message could be:

> Your image is too large to upload (over 2 MB).
>
> You could try:
>
> 1. Compressing it using [tinypng.com](http://tinypng.com)
> 2. Resizing or cropping the image
> 3. Choosing a different image

The new error could look like:

[image: New error]

Another option is for it to be internally resized before publishing it to imgur.

Comment: What if SO just resized it internally before pushing to Imgur?

Comment: @TheWanderer Could be a possibility but that would need implementing on all sites.

Comment: @DManokhin oops, I meant to say SE.

Comment: But don't you think anyone savvy enough to upload an image from their home computer or mobile device, should have enough wit to know the image has to be either cropped or substituted. Don't all computer desktops have that very basic tool for reducing the resolution of images in all their operating systems? You don't need Photoshop or an external website. I dunno... I'm 52 and very very unsavvy where computers are concerned but this seems to be basic stuff.

Comment: related suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317672/237989