# What is exactly displayed on the upload progress indicator?

Tags: support, bug, firefox, uploader

After [updating the image upload dialog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/339911) I can't actually understand what is exactly displayed on the image upload indicator.

> [image: upload circle]

For me it looks like some randomly distributed points on the rotated circle. Is there some kind of background of this animation origin?

This was tested on Windows 7 and Firefox 64.0 with scale factor 100%.

Comment: Maybe the video drivers are out of date. Can you try to reproduce without hardware acceleration: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/performance-settings?as=u&utm_source=inproduct

Comment: @rene disabling hw acceleration change nothing. Has tried after restart the FF.

Comment: I repro-ed now on an NVIDIA GeForce GT 620 driver: 23.21.13.8813 (Windows 10 OS)

Comment: What's yer zoom level? Also, [what's wrong with this image](https://example.com/madeyoulook)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr** A normal spinner

I tried to find this out by looking on how this spinner is generated. Fortunately Stack Exchange documented their styles quite well on [stackoverflow.design](https://stackoverflow.design). They developed a framework called *Stacks*.

This button style is generated by the class `is-loading`. At first I looked whether it is an SVG but it uses an other trick.

They generate an pseudo-element (`::before`) on the button that contains the following code:

```css
.s-btn.is-loading::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 8px);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-left: -1.65em;
    margin-left: -22px;
    border: 2px dotted rgba(57,115,157,.4);
    border-left-color: #33658a;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spinnerRotate .8s infinite linear;
}
```

This should generate a rotating circle with equally distributed dots, like in this zoomed in picture:

[image]

I just tried the image uploader and it seems like I can't reproduce this problem. Therefore I think it is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) only ocurring in certain browsers. Maybe consider changing your question to a bug-report or start a new question.

---

I have put the important code in a snippet. If you execute this snippet you should see the same effect. (If you don't want to try the image uploader)

```css
.loader::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-left: -1.65em;
  margin-left: -22px;
  border: 2px dotted rgba(57, 115, 157, .4);
  border-left-color: #33658a;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spinnerRotate .8s infinite linear;
}

.loader {
  padding-left: 2.2em;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes spinnerRotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader">&larr; Loader</div>
```

Comment: I think the blur/grey that is added on click might as well contribute to the "awkward"  rendering of the CSS animation

Comment: @rene I wouldn't be so sure about this. If you look [here](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/buttons#loading). I can't reproduce the problem on any of the button variants, not even on the disabled ones.

Comment: They also seem fine to me. So no repro on chrome for sure.

Comment: Neither on Firefox and Chrome for iOS. Let’s see what the OP has for a browser/system. @rene

Comment: Your loader from the snippet looks [almost the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9XYq.gif) as SE indicator for me in FF. Chrome browser displays the both indicators in [more clear way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq2JA.gif).

Comment: @älёxölüt yes it is intended as a simple way to reproduce the problem without uploading tons of images to Imgur. They use basically the same code. // Strange probably it is some unlucky software and hardware combination.

Comment: it is definitely an issue in FF on older hardware: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWhYU.png, this is on an NVidia GeForce GT620.

Comment: @rene please send me a modern hardware on my next bday :) What hw is considered old?

Comment: @rene okay. Could YOU edit this to my answer? I am currently on mobile and editing markdown is really hard.  :)

Comment: @rene my GPU is much [older than yours](https://gpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Nvidia-GTX-560-vs-Nvidia-GeForce-GT-620/3155vsm8899), but in the same time is more productive.