# Edit your profile page still uses old image uploader

Tags: bug, profile-page, uploader

**Update:** Turns out this was [previously reported in an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317622/148310).

When going to `/users/edit/{UserID}` on any site it still uses the old image uploader in the editor.

Is this a bug? Is it intentional? Can this get updated?

Screen video of bug in action (in spoiler to avoid triggering epileptic attacks):

> [image: gif showing old uploader]

Comment: Well, since it seems that the code is not [DRY](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself), that is a bug in my shop.

Comment: @Awesome neither is this post. ;) This has been posted already: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317622/364003

Comment: @AwesomePoodles I don’t blame you. I just made an reference to your DRY comment. ;)

Comment: @MEE, related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322382/should-bug-report-feature-request-questions-that-duplicate-grab-bag-answers (Hopefully **it** isn't a dupe; I did search for previous posts).

Comment: Same uploader is used if you’re about to change profile picture during sign up process.