# Followed posts displays a "Q" icon even for answers

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface, follow-post

There's a minor bug with viewing followed posts on your own profile: posts get a **Q** icon whether they're questions or answers.

Here's a screenshot from when I view that section in my own RPG.SE meta profile:

[image: screenshot of my followed posts: a “Q” icon, their score, and the question title.]

**The second post is an answer.** It links to that answer, and it displays the answer's score (not the question's score), which is all correct. However it has a **Q** icon which is incorrect. It should have an **A** icon instead. Here's a mockup of what I mean:

[image: fixed version of the above screenshot, with the second post having an “A” icon instead]

Comment: This has been mentioned in [this report](/a/372645/289905).

Comment: Thank you for the report; closing this as per [common Meta practice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322382/295232).