# "Max 2 MiB" and "Provide a link from the web" strings overlap in the profile-pic uploader on SO in Russian

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, uploader, russian-stackoverflow

On [SO in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), the "Max 2 MiB" and "Provide a link from the web" strings overlap in the profile-picture uploader:

[image]

And when actually uploading the picture.  It's fine on [SO in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com):

[image]

Can we fix that?

Comment: The image uploader on profile pages is still the old one.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog for ru.SO, or for them all?

Comment: On all sites, not just that one.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog And are there plans to change that, or... ?

Comment: This was [requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317622/377214) at the time the new uploader launched, but was marked deferred at that time.