# Why is there no highlight and drag for moving blocks of text inside the input box?

Tags: support, edits, editor

When I compose or edit posts I often find that words or phrases are better suited in a different order and wish to move them. However, I am reminded by the  *(prohibited)* symbol that I can not do this. Is this something specific to StackExchange sites?

Comment: They are using the WMD editor: https://github.com/StackExchange/pagedown. It might be that they don't accept text drop because they already subscribed to image drop.

Comment: It does work in comments so it is certainly not something specific to an SE site, just local to the post editor.

Comment: This _does_ actually work in the new [alpha Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/165261).

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317576/editor-improvements-for-images-and-links

Comment: you can change any thing  what are you talking about

Comment: @RyanM okay thanks. The answer is now moot. Go ahead and bury it yall.

Comment: Instead of editing this multiple times to test out the new editor, why not try the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) instead?

Comment: i actualy was only fixing my own grammar.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Drag and drop of text is a distinct feature of 'Rich Text formatting' in editors as opposed to 'markdown' where a user needs to know the syntax or 'coding'. SE already uses Commonmark editing and use drag and drop with images, so that option is unavailable for text.

This is my own poorly scripted answer based on comments, as a way to test the [new SE editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) currently in alpha. Click the link to read about it and decide whether to opt in.